# Programar modo nocturno en Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Necesito que al pulsar un botón, el usuario pueda cambiar entre modo nocturno o modo día. No he trabajado mucho con `Android Studio` así que estoy aprendiendo. Tengo en `styles.xml` este código:

```
<resources>

        <!-- Base application theme. -->
        <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
            <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
            <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
            <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
            <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        </style>

        <style name="AppTheme.2" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight">
            <item name="android:background">#26262b</item>
        </style>
    </resources>
```

Y quiero que en el main:

```
FloatingActionButton fab;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
         fab = findViewById(R.id.color);


        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {


            }
        });
```

Al darle a ese botón se ponga el fondo negro. He estado viendo tutoriales pero no logro entenderlo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La opción que puedes tomar es utilizando los estilos o style en este caso te recomiendo revisar esta pagina que explica muy bien como hacer aunque esta en ingles: https://carthrottle.io/how-to-implement-flexible-night-mode-in-your-android-app-f00f0f83b70e

En todo caso lo que tienes que hacer primero es crearte el archivo attrs.xml en la carpeta values.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Colocas el nombre del archivo **attrs.xml**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Luego debes agregar el siguiente codigo:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="CTAppTheme">
        <attr name="primaryTextColor" format="color"/>
        <attr name="secondaryTextColor" format="color"/>
        <attr name="dividerColor" format="color"/>
        <attr name="backgroundCardColor" format="color"/>
        <attr name="iconPlaceholder" format="integer"/>
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

En la cual dices que los siguientes atributos tienen los siguientes formatos en este caso para los que son netamente color es "color" y para aquellos que son recursos como imagenes es un "integer" ya que se referencian con la clase R.

Seguidamente en el archivo **style.xml** agregas el siguiente codigo:

```
<!-- Light base activity theme -->
<style name="ActivityTheme.Primary.Base.Light" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="primaryTextColor">#F4F4F6</item>
    <item name="secondaryTextColor">#96F4F4F6</item>
    <item name="backgroundCardColor">#FFFF</item>
    <item name="dividerColor">#F2F2F3</item>
    <item name="iconPlaceholder">@drawable/i_light_plholder</item>
</style>
<!-- Dark base activity theme -->
<style name="ActivityTheme.Primary.Base.Dark"    parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="primaryTextColor">#33343B/item>
    <item name="secondaryTextColor">#8033343B</item>
    <item name="backgroundCardColor">#28292e</item>
    <item name="dividerColor">#F2F2F3</item>
    <item name="iconPlaceholder">@drawable/i_dark_pholder</item>
</style>
```

Aqui es donde dices cada atributo que valor va tener para cada estilo tanto para el claro como para el oscuro, y si te fijas tambien para el caso de imagenes o recursos, esto para los ejemplos de este tipo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La imagen de la carita es distinta por cada estilo.

Seguidamente colocamos mas abajo de los estilos el siguiente fragmento de codigo:

```
<!-- Specific Feed activity theme -->
<style name="FeedActivityThemeLight" parent="ActivityTheme.Primary.Base.Light">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">#F4F4F6</item>
</style>
<style name="FeedActivityThemeDark" parent="ActivityTheme.Primary.Base.Dark">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">#33343B</item>
</style>
```

Donde estos son los estilos que heredaran de los anteriores estilos.
Por ultimo solo debes utilizarlo en los layout asi:

```
       <ImageView
           android:id="@+id/placeHolderAssetImageView"
           android:layout_width="100dp"
           android:layout_height="100dp"
           android:src="?attr/iconPlaceholder"
           android:layout_marginBottom="8dp" />
       <TextView
           android:id="@+id/placeHolderTitleTextView"
           android:text="Post not found."
           android:textSize="16dp"
           android:textColor="?attr/primaryTextColor"
           android:layout_margin="16dp" />
```

si te fijas en el **ImageView** en el src esta con ?attr/iconPlaceholder esto para que tome el recurso segun el estilo de la aplicación de igual forma el textColor del **TextView**

Seguidamente debes guardar en algun lado la preferencia de si es oscuro o claro esto para que no tengas q cambiar a cada rato en tu actividad, para ello se recomienda usar las SharePreferences para guardar como preferencia, luego obtenerlo en la actividad. Tambien te recomendaria usarla en la clase Application para no tener que crear a cada rato la instancia de la clase de preferencias.

public class App extends Application {
          public static final String TAG = "App";
          private boolean isNightModeEnabled = false;

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
     super.onCreate();
     // cargamos la preferencia 
     SharedPreferences mPrefs =  PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
     this.isNightModeEnabled = mPrefs.getBoolean(“NIGHT_MODE”, false);
 }

 public boolean isNightModeEnabled() {
       return isNightModeEnabled;
 }

 public void setIsNightModeEnabled(boolean isNightModeEnabled) {
       this.isNightModeEnabled = isNightModeEnabled;
 }
```

}

Por ultimo en tu actividad colocas lo siguiente:

```
FloatingActionButton fab;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

       if (MyApplication.getInstance().isNightModeEnabled()) {
           setTheme(R.style.FeedActivityThemeDark);
       }

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
         fab = findViewById(R.id.color);

      fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                       Intent intent = getIntent();
                       finish();
                       startActivity(intent);

                }
            });
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por el post, pero estoy teniendo algunos problemas con el código. Imagino que la parte de `if (MyApplication.getInstance().isNightModeEnabled()) {
           setTheme(R.style.FeedActivityThemeDark);
       }` Myapplication es para el nombre de la app. Sin embargo cuando pongo el mio me da un error y no me reconoce el nombre. Y el otro problema que no he sabido solventar en esta linea de Código `this.isNightModeEnabled = mPrefs.getBoolean(“NIGHT_MODE”, false);` NIGHT_MODE  me da error. Cannot resolve symbol

Comment: Bueno como te mencionaba esa clase solamente es para guardar la preferencia donde se usara la proxima vez que uses la aplicación iniciara con ese modo. No es obligatorio que lo tengas la clase Application, puede usar tambien el en mismo activity. En todo caso te aconsejaria que revises esta pagina para entender como se usan las preferencias: http://www.sgoliver.net/blog/preferencias-en-android-i-shared-preferences/

Comment: A la hora de compilar me pone lo siguiente : values.xml:2042: error: expected reference but got (raw string) #33343B.  values.xml:2045: error: expected reference but got (raw string) #F4F4F6. Se que son estas dos lineas de código las que me dan error, pero no se como solucionarlo. `<style name="FeedActivityThemeLight" parent="ActivityTheme.Primary.Base.Light">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">#F4F4F6</item>
    </style>
    <style name="FeedActivityThemeDark" parent="ActivityTheme.Primary.Base.Dark">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">#33343B</item>
    </style>`

Answer (score 0):

También puedes activar el modo nocturno de esta manera:

```
 AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);
  recreate();  //Modo claro


 AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);
   recreate(); //Modo nocturno
```

Además de eso tienes que crear una carpeta values-night que cuando Mode Night este activado este entra en función, y en el cual debes crear un xml para los colores por ejemplo:

```
colors.xml
<color name="background">#ffffff</color>

colors.xml  //night
<color name="background">#001d38</color>
```

Ambos archivos deben de tener la misma cantidad de colores. 
Y solamente tienes que enlazarla con los textviews, layouts etc. que tengas, si quieres que cambie de color según el modo, ejemplo:

```
  <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/background"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:padding="5dp"/>
```

Espero te ayude, saludos.